# How can I make my bouncy balls change color after they collide with each other in JavaScript and an HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I am creating a sort of physics simulation where a bunch of balls with different radii bounce against each other and the walls. To make it look better before I refactor, I would like to make the balls change color upon collision, but I'm not sure where I should add it in, or how.

Note: The color should be randomized by using

`randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);`

`color = "#" + randomColor;`

Note: Only the balls involved in the collision should change color. So if two balls touch, they should both change color, but no other.

**Question**: How can I make it so that after every collision, the balls change color?

```js
function lineMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').textContent += msg + '. ';
}

function groupMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').innerHTML += msg + '<br/>';
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 550;
const ballCount = document.querySelector('#ball-count');

const gravity = 0;
const wallLoss = 1;
let numBalls = 0;  // approx as will not add ball if space can not be found
const minBallSize = 10;
const maxBallSize = 100;
const velMin = 1;
const velMax = 5; 
const maxResolutionCycles = 100;

Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
Math.rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
Math.randI = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min | 0; // only for positive numbers 32bit signed int
Math.randItem = arr => arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0]; // only for arrays with length < 2 ** 31 - 1

//contact points of two circles radius r1, r2 moving along two lines (a,e)-(b,f) and (c,g)-(d,h)
Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime = (a, e, b, f, c, g, d, h, r1, r2) => {
    const A = a * a, B = b * b, C = c * c, D = d * d;
    const E = e * e, F = f * f, G = g * g, H = h * h;
    var R = (r1 + r2) ** 2;
    const AA = A + B + C + F + G + H + D + E + b * c + c * b + f * g + g * f + 2 * (a * d - a * b - a * c - b * d - c * d - e * f + e * h - e * g - f * h - g * h);
    const BB = 2 * (-A + a * b + 2 * a * c - a * d - c * b - C + c * d - E + e * f + 2 * e * g - e * h - g * f - G + g * h);
    const CC = A - 2 * a * c + C + E - 2 * e * g + G - R;
    return Math.quadRoots(AA, BB, CC);
}  

Math.quadRoots = (a, b, c) => { // find roots for quadratic
    if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-6) {
        return b != 0 ? [-c / b] : [] 
    }

    b /= a;
    var d = b * b - 4 * (c / a);

    if (d > 0) {
        d = d ** 0.5;
        return  [0.5 * (-b + d), 0.5 * (-b - d)]
    }

    return d === 0 ? [0.5 * -b] : [];
}

Math.interceptLineBallTime = (x, y, vx, vy, x1, y1, x2, y2, r) => {
    const xx = x2 - x1;
    const yy = y2 - y1;
    const d = vx * yy - vy * xx;

    if (d > 0) {  // only if moving towards the line
        const dd = r / (xx * xx + yy * yy) ** 0.5;
        const nx = xx * dd;
        const ny = yy * dd;
        return (xx * (y - (y1 + nx)) - yy * (x - (x1 - ny))) / d;
    }
}

const balls = [];
const lines = [];

function Line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
}

Line.prototype = {
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
    },
    reverse() {
        const x = this.x1;
        const y = this.y1;
        this.x1 = this.x2;
        this.y1 = this.y2;
        this.x2 = x;
        this.y2 = y;
        return this;
    }
}
        
function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r = 45, m = 4 / 3 * Math.PI * (r ** 3)) {
    this.r = r;
    this.m = m;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
}

Ball.prototype = {
    update() {
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
        this.vy += gravity;
    },
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.r, this.y);
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.TAU);
    },
    interceptLineTime(l, time) {
        const u = Math.interceptLineBallTime(this.x, this.y, this.vx, this.vy, l.x1, l.y1, l.x2, l.y2, this.r);

        if (u >= time && u <= 1) {
            return u;
        }
    },
    checkBallBallTime(t, minTime) {
        return t > minTime && t <= 1;
    },
    interceptBallTime(b, time) {
        const x = this.x - b.x;
        const y = this.y - b.y;
        const d = (x * x + y * y) ** 0.5;

        if (d > this.r + b.r) {
            const times = Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime(
                this.x, this.y, 
                this.x + this.vx, this.y + this.vy, 
                b.x, b.y,
                b.x + b.vx, b.y + b.vy, 
                this.r, b.r
            )

            if (times.length) {
                if (times.length === 1) {
                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                        return times[0]
                    }

                    return;
                }

                if (times[0] <= times[1]) {
                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                        return times[0]
                    }

                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) {
                        return times[1]
                    }

                    return
                }

                if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) { 
                    return times[1]
                }      

                if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                    return times[0]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    collideLine(l, time) {
        const x1 = l.x2 - l.x1;
        const y1 = l.y2 - l.y1;
        const d = (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1) ** 0.5;
        const nx = x1 / d;
        const ny = y1 / d;            
        const u = (this.vx  * nx + this.vy  * ny) * 2;
        this.x += this.vx * time;   
        this.y += this.vy * time;   
        this.vx = (nx * u - this.vx) * wallLoss;
        this.vy = (ny * u - this.vy) * wallLoss;
        this.x -= this.vx * time;
        this.y -= this.vy * time;
    },
    collide(b, time) {
        const a = this;
        const m1 = a.m;
        const m2 = b.m;
        const x = a.x - b.x
        const y = a.y - b.y  
        const d = (x * x + y * y);
        const u1 = (a.vx * x + a.vy * y) / d
        const u2 = (x * a.vy - y * a.vx ) / d
        const u3 = (b.vx * x + b.vy * y) / d
        const u4 = (x * b.vy - y * b.vx ) / d
        const mm = m1 + m2;
        const vu3 = (m1 - m2) / mm * u1 + (2 * m2) / mm * u3;
        const vu1 = (m2 - m1) / mm * u3 + (2 * m1) / mm * u1;
        a.x = a.x + a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y + a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x + b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y + b.vy * time;
        b.vx = x * vu1 - y * u4;
        b.vy = y * vu1 + x * u4;
        a.vx = x * vu3 - y * u2;
        a.vy = y * vu3 + x * u2;
        a.x = a.x - a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y - a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x - b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y - b.vy * time;
    },
    doesOverlap(ball) {
        const x = this.x - ball.x;
        const y = this.y - ball.y;
        return  (this.r + ball.r) > ((x * x + y * y) ** 0.5);  
    }       
}

function canAdd(ball) {
    for (const b of balls) {
        if (ball.doesOverlap(b)) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function create(bCount) {
    //Instead of doing bCount = 1, you can also do create(1)
    bCount = 1;
    lines.push(new Line(-10, 10, ctx.canvas.width + 10, 5));
    lines.push((new Line(-10, ctx.canvas.height - 2, ctx.canvas.width + 10, ctx.canvas.height - 10)).reverse());
    lines.push((new Line(10, -10, 4, ctx.canvas.height + 10)).reverse());
    lines.push(new Line(ctx.canvas.width - 3, -10, ctx.canvas.width - 10, ctx.canvas.height + 10)); 

    while (bCount--) {
        let tries = 100;
        debugger

        while (tries--) {
            const dir = Math.rand(0, Math.TAU);
            const vel = Math.rand(velMin, velMax);
            const ball = new Ball(
                Math.rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.width - maxBallSize - 10), 
                Math.rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.height - maxBallSize - 10),
                Math.cos(dir) * vel,
                Math.sin(dir) * vel,
                Math.rand(minBallSize, maxBallSize),
            )

            if (canAdd(ball)) {
                balls.push(ball);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function resolveCollisions() {
    var minTime = 0, minObj, minBall, resolving = true, idx = 0, idx1, after = 0, e = 0;
        
    while (resolving && e++ < maxResolutionCycles) { // too main ball may create very lone resolution cycle. e limits this
        resolving = false;
        minObj = undefined;
        minBall = undefined;
        minTime = 1;
        idx = 0;

        for(const b of balls) {
            idx1 = idx + 1;
            while (idx1 < balls.length) {
                const b1 = balls[idx1++];
                const time = b.interceptBallTime(b1, after);

                if (time !== undefined) {
                    if (time <= minTime) {
                         minTime = time;
                        minObj = b1;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (const l of lines) {
                 const time = b.interceptLineTime(l, after);
                if (time !== undefined) {
                    if (time <= minTime) {
                        minTime = time;
                        minObj = l;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            idx++;
        }

        if (resolving) {
            if (minObj instanceof Ball) {
                minBall.collide(minObj, minTime);
            } else {
                minBall.collideLine(minObj, minTime);
            }

            after = minTime;
        }
    }
}

function mainLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    resolveCollisions();

    for (const b of balls) {
        b.update()
    }

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();

    for (const b of balls) {
        b.draw()
    }

    for (const l of lines) {
        l.draw()
    }

    ctx.stroke();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}    

function addBall() {
    numBalls++;
    ballCount.innerHTML = numBalls;
    //Instead of doing create(numBalls), you can do create(1)
    create(numBalls);
}

mainLoop();
```

```css
#canvas {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 550px
}

#myConsole {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <title>Bouncy Balls</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="addBall()">Add Ball</button><br>
        <div>Ball Count: <span id="ball-count">0</span></div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <p id="myConsole">&gt;&nbsp;<span id="myMessage"></span></p>

        <script src="app2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Voting to close because I think it needs more focus.    The problem is you are drawing all your arcs for the balls and then doing one call to stroke.   You need to set the stroke style and stroke for each ball for them to have different colors.   With the code you've written I think you can figure out how to store the color associated with the ball.

Comment: Quite a nice animation, but the code could indeed use some refactoring. I think you could put the color change in `collide()`. You know that `a` and `b` are colliding and you're moving them away from each other. When you refactor, please refer to balls as balls. You can use `ballA` and `ballB` but not `a` and `b`, or any of the many other variants you have. Variable naming is an important aspect in making your code readable. Names should be meaningful and describe function, consistently throughout your code.

Comment: There's nothing needing focus about this at all; it presents a very clear and narrowly-scoped question: how to make balls change color when they collide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code generates a color for a ball which you just created:

```
const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    a.color = "#" + randomColor;
    b.color = "#" + randomColor;
```

Here in this function `Ball(....)` the code generates a new color when 2 or more balls collide:

`this.color = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);`

Here is the correct version:

```js
function lineMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').textContent += msg + '. ';
}

function groupMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').innerHTML += msg + '<br/>';
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 550;
const ballCount = document.querySelector('#ball-count');

const gravity = 0;
const wallLoss = 1;
let numBalls = 0;
const minBallSize = 10;
const maxBallSize = 100;
const velMin = 1;
const velMax = 5;
const maxResolutionCycles = 100;

Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
Math.rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
Math.randI = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min | 0;
Math.randItem = arr => arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0];

Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime = (a, e, b, f, c, g, d, h, r1, r2) => {
    const A = a * a, B = b * b, C = c * c, D = d * d;
    const E = e * e, F = f * f, G = g * g, H = h * h;
    var R = (r1 + r2) ** 2;
    const AA = A + B + C + F + G + H + D + E + b * c + c * b + f * g + g * f + 2 * (a * d - a * b - a * c - b * d - c * d - e * f + e * h - e * g - f * h - g * h);
    const BB = 2 * (-A + a * b + 2 * a * c - a * d - c * b - C + c * d - E + e * f + 2 * e * g - e * h - g * f - G + g * h);
    const CC = A - 2 * a * c + C + E - 2 * e * g + G - R;
    return Math.quadRoots(AA, BB, CC);
}

Math.quadRoots = (a, b, c) => {
    if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-6) {
        return b != 0 ? [-c / b] : [];
    }

    b /= a;
    var d = b * b - 4 * (c / a);

    if (d > 0) {
        d = d ** 0.5;
        return [0.5 * (-b + d), 0.5 * (-b - d)];
    }

    return d === 0 ? [0.5 * -b] : [];
}

Math.interceptLineBallTime = (x, y, vx, vy, x1, y1, x2, y2, r) => {
    const xx = x2 - x1;
    const yy = y2 - y1;
    const d = vx * yy - vy * xx;

    if (d > 0) {
        const dd = r / (xx * xx + yy * yy) ** 0.5;
        const nx = xx * dd;
        const ny = yy * dd;
        return (xx * (y - (y1 + nx)) - yy * (x - (x1 - ny))) / d;
    }
}

const balls = [];
const lines = [];

function Line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
}

Line.prototype = {
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
    },
    reverse() {
        const x = this.x1;
        const y = this.y1;
        this.x1 = this.x2;
        this.y1 = this.y2;
        this.x2 = x;
        this.y2 = y;
        return this;
    }
}

function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r = 45, m = 4 / 3 * Math.PI * (r ** 3)) {
    this.r = r;
    this.m = m;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
    this.color = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16); // Initialize with a random color
}

Ball.prototype = {
    update() {
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;
        this.vy += gravity;
    },
    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color; // Set the fill color to the ball's color
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.TAU);
        ctx.fill();
    },
    interceptLineTime(l, time) {
        const u = Math.interceptLineBallTime(this.x, this.y, this.vx, this.vy, l.x1, l.y1, l.x2, l.y2, this.r);

        if (u >= time && u <= 1) {
            return u;
        }
    },
    checkBallBallTime(t, minTime) {
        return t > minTime && t <= 1;
    },
    interceptBallTime(b, time) {
        const x = this.x - b.x;
        const y = this.y - b.y;
        const d = (x * x + y * y) ** 0.5;

        if (d > this.r + b.r) {
            const times = Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime(
                this.x, this.y,
                this.x + this.vx, this.y + this.vy,
                b.x, b.y,
                b.x + b.vx, b.y + b.vy,
                this.r, b.r
            )

            if (times.length) {
                if (times.length === 1) {
                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                        return times[0]
                    }

                    return;
                }

                if (times[0] <= times[1]) {
                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                        return times[0]
                    }

                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) {
                        return times[1]
                    }

                    return
                }

                if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) {
                    return times[1]
                }

                if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                    return times[0]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    collideLine(l, time) {
        const x1 = l.x2 - l.x1;
        const y1 = l.y2 - l.y1;
        const d = (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1) ** 0.5;
        const nx = x1 / d;
        const ny = y1 / d;
        const u = (this.vx * nx + this.vy * ny) * 2;
        this.x += this.vx * time;
        this.y += this.vy * time;
        this.vx = (nx * u - this.vx) * wallLoss;
        this.vy = (ny * u - this.vy) * wallLoss;
        this.x -= this.vx * time;
        this.y -= this.vy * time;
    },
    collide(b, time) {
        const a = this;
        const m1 = a.m;
        const m2 = b.m;
        const x = a.x - b.x;
        const y = a.y - b.y;
        const d = (x * x + y * y);
        const u1 = (a.vx * x + a.vy * y) / d;
        const u2 = (x * a.vy - y * a.vx) / d;
        const u3 = (b.vx * x + b.vy * y) / d;
        const u4 = (x * b.vy - y * b.vx) / d;
        const mm = m1 + m2;
        const vu3 = (m1 - m2) / mm * u1 + (2 * m2) / mm * u3;
        const vu1 = (m2 - m1) / mm * u3 + (2 * m1) / mm * u1;
        a.x = a.x + a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y + a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x + b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y + b.vy * time;
        b.vx = x * vu1 - y * u4;
        b.vy = y * vu1 + x * u4;
        a.vx = x * vu3 - y * u2;
        a.vy = y * vu3 + x * u2;
        a.x = a.x - a.vx * time;
        a.y = a.y - a.vy * time;
        b.x = b.x - b.vx * time;
        b.y = b.y - b.vy * time;

        // Change color upon collision
        const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        a.color = "#" + randomColor;
        b.color = "#" + randomColor;
    },
    doesOverlap(ball) {
        const x = this.x - ball.x;
        const y = this.y - ball.y;
        return (this.r + ball.r) > ((x * x + y * y) ** 0.5);
    }
}

function canAdd(ball) {
    for (const b of balls) {
        if (ball.doesOverlap(b)) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function create(bCount) {
    bCount = 1;
    lines.push(new Line(-10, 10, ctx.canvas.width + 10, 5));
    lines.push((new Line(-10, ctx.canvas.height - 2, ctx.canvas.width + 10, ctx.canvas.height - 10)).reverse());
    lines.push((new Line(10, -10, 4, ctx.canvas.height + 10)).reverse());
    lines.push(new Line(ctx.canvas.width - 3, -10, ctx.canvas.width - 10, ctx.canvas.height + 10));

    while (bCount--) {
        let tries = 100;
        debugger

        while (tries--) {
            const dir = Math.rand(0, Math.TAU);
            const vel = Math.rand(velMin, velMax);
            const ball = new Ball(
                Math.rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.width - maxBallSize - 10),
                Math.rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.height - maxBallSize - 10),
                Math.cos(dir) * vel,
                Math.sin(dir) * vel,
                Math.rand(minBallSize, maxBallSize),
            )

            if (canAdd(ball)) {
                balls.push(ball);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function resolveCollisions() {
    var minTime = 0, minObj, minBall, resolving = true, idx = 0, idx1, after = 0, e = 0;

    while (resolving && e++ < maxResolutionCycles) {
        resolving = false;
        minObj = undefined;
        minBall = undefined;
        minTime = 1;
        idx = 0;

        for (const b of balls) {
            idx1 = idx + 1;
            while (idx1 < balls.length) {
                const b1 = balls[idx1++];
                const time = b.interceptBallTime(b1, after);

                if (time !== undefined) {
                    if (time <= minTime) {
                        minTime = time;
                        minObj = b1;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (const l of lines) {
                const time = b.interceptLineTime(l, after);
                if (time !== undefined) {
                    if (time <= minTime) {
                        minTime = time;
                        minObj = l;
                        minBall = b;
                        resolving = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            idx++;
        }

        if (resolving) {
            if (minObj instanceof Ball) {
                minBall.collide(minObj, minTime);
            } else {
                minBall.collideLine(minObj, minTime);
            }

            after = minTime;
        }
    }
}

function mainLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    resolveCollisions();

    for (const b of balls) {
        b.update()
    }

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();

    for (const b of balls) {
        b.draw()
    }

    for (const l of lines) {
        l.draw()
    }

    ctx.stroke();
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

function addBall() {
    numBalls++;
    ballCount.innerHTML = numBalls;
    create(1);
}

mainLoop();
```

```css
#canvas {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 550px
}

#myConsole {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <title>Bouncy Balls</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="addBall()">Add Ball</button><br>
        <div>Ball Count: <span id="ball-count">0</span></div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <p id="myConsole">&gt;&nbsp;<span id="myMessage"></span></p>

        <script src="app2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```